# How do I take Nokogiri-scraped HTML and output it as UTF-8 to the terminal?

Tags: html, ruby, encoding, utf-8, nokogiri

I'm *very* new to programming, and am writing a small practice program in Ruby 1.9.3 that uses Nokogiri to query the Canadian parliamentary website with a postal code, and then prints the name of the corresponding Member of Parliament and their riding to the terminal.

My code fetches the page and isolates the MP's name/riding just fine, but displays UTF-8 characters as plain ASCII in the shell.  I want the UTF-8 characters to be displayed instead.

I know the shell can handle UTF-8 because:

```
irb> riding = "St-Jérôme"
=> "St-Jérôme"
irb> puts riding
St-Jérôme
=> nil
```

The code I'm using to fetch the page:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://parl.gc.ca/ParlInfo/Compilations/HouseOfCommons/MemberByPostalCode.aspx?PostalCode=#{postalcode}"))
```

This is a sample of what this code returns when I type `puts page`:

```
<span id="ctl00_cphContent_repMP_ctl00_grdConstituencyAddress_ctl02_Label12">St-J&Atilde;&copy;r&Atilde;&acute;me</span>
```

So "`St-Jérôme`" becomes "`St-J&Atilde;&copy;r&Atilde;&acute;me`" in the page output, or just "`St-J&Atilde;&copy;r&Atilde;&acute;me`" in the terminal.

Maybe there's a method to convert it while it's stored as a string variable?  Or maybe there's an option I can set in Nokogiri which will pull it down as UTF-8 instead of ASCII?

I searched for a long time to find an answer on Google and Stack Overflow, and haven't found anything either relevant or that I understand; Again, I'm very new at this. If this is a duplicate, please point me in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Comment: We need more/better information. What is the postal code you're using? We need a sample of the code you're using, not just to retrieve the URL, but the tag you want. See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://parl.gc.ca/ParlInfo/Compilations/HouseOfCommons/MemberByPostalCode.aspx?PostalCode=#{postalcode}"), nil, "UTF-8")
```

instead. This should parse the page as UTF-8 and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

@BadgerPriest has the answer. Here's why: Check the source for [Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/Document.html#method-c-parse).

Nokogiri relies on LibXML2, to handle parsing, but LibXML2 doesn't do a good job determining the correct character encoding of the document being parsed. Nokogiri punts and defaults to ASCII-8bit, which results in the multibyte characters being mangled.

By forcing the encoding to UTF-8, Nokogiri is in line with the page's encoding, and it's able to return and/or display the characters correctly.

HTML pages are a real mixed bag when it comes to the encoding matching the actual payload inside them. It's very common to see encodings that have no relationship to the actual characters, so we often have to tell Nokogiri what to interpret the HTML as. It's ugly, but it's the state of the Internet's "wealth" of legacy HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I was told by a programmer friend that I should learn to use Nokogiri, and have been finding the documentation a little hard to understand -- I'm also relatively new to HTML/CSS/XML which doesn't help.  I appreciate you taking the time to explain it for me.

Comment: Yes, Nokogiri is a great tool to know, and once you're comfortable parsing and doing lookups, you'll wonder why anyone would use any other method of dealing with XML/HTML. Dealing with either via a regex is almost primitive in comparison.